# Unusual error using bcrypt in Flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, bcrypt

I have a problem using bcrypt in my Flask application. I'm trying to verify if the password entered by an user is equal to the password in the db, but it throw me an error that is apparently inside the library. I don't know how to fix that, thank you for the help!

[image: AttributeError: module 'bcrypt._bcrypt' has no attribute 'hashpass']

I believed the problem was inside my application, but it wasn't.
I also tried to reinstall the bcrypt library and the Flask one.
Online there I didn't find anything at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error recently and I found out that bcrypt was conflicting with py-bcrypt, Uninstall both bcyrpt and py-bcrypt , then install py-bcrypt.

```
pip uninstall bcrypt
pip uninstall py-bcrypt

pip install py-bcrypt
```